# PHP dynamic dropdown menu list

Tags: php

I have created a dynamic dropdown menu list which lists a column in a database. I can get that to show up fine but when I want to submit a result and POST that to another file all I get is an 'undefined' index error. Here is the last aprt of my index.php file.

```
   <select name="bob">
    <?php
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
        extract ($row);
        echo "<option value='$forename'>$forename</option>\n";
        }
            ?>
            </select>

        <form action='processnames.php' method='POST'>
        <input type='submit' value='Submit' />
        </form> </body> </html>
```

The processnames.php has the following code:

```
    Welcome <?php 
    session_start();
    echo $_POST["bob"]; ?><br />
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to put your `select` box inside the `<form>` tags:

```
    <form action='processnames.php' method='POST'>
    <select name="bob">
    <?php
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
      extract ($row);
      echo "<option value='$forename'>$forename</option>\n";
    }
    ?>
    </select>

    <input type='submit' value='Submit' />
    </form> </body> </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The select tag needs to be in-between your form tags.  Right now it's outside of your form.